# iPython Ctrl + L no longer working

Tags: python, ipython

I updated my iPython to 4.0.3, and when I did I had a few issues. At first, it seemed I had to reinstall pyreadline to make all the syntax appear as normal again. Now, my biggest problem is that `Ctrl + L` no longer works to clear my screen. Typing `clear` does or `clear-screen`. I have edited the config file and uncommented

`c.InteractiveShell.readline_parse_and_bind`

which has

`'"\\C-l": clear-screen'`

but all this does is insert a new line into my terminal. It's not a huge problem, but it is an annoyance. I have tried a few combinations of different `C-l` commands in my config, but so far nothing has worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: IPython also uses .inputrc, but things in that config value take precedence, and sometimes Ctrl+L is in there by default.

Comment: I don't see a Ctrl + L in my inputrc. I only have the one in ```/etc/inputrc```. Ctrl + L does still work in my normal terminal though.